# Using the goto command as a fallback in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I make it so that when the folder can't be found, the code will use the `goto` command?

Here's my code:

```
:T
Echo Folder is Already Unlocked

:CODE
if attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309B}" goto T
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309B}" Codes
call :c 09 " Codes Unlocked successfully
goto UNLOCK
```

Comment: Are you asking "goto T if the target object has both athhributes S and H" or do you want to goto T if the `attrib` command returns errorlevel 0 having reset the H and S attributes on the target, or do you want to attempt to reset those attributes, then check it happened or what? You have to explain the objective of your code; most of us aren't psychic. We can conclude your code isn't doing what you want it to do, otherwise you wouldn't ask a question.

Comment: the code is meant to act as a lock for a flash drive. i want it to go to T when "if attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309B}" goto T" command fails

Comment: If that command fails, then in all probability, `errorlevel` will become non-zero (I haven't tried it and don't have time at present.) If this is the case, then execute the `attrib` command, then the next batch line is `if errorlevel 1 goto t`

Comment: I kinda just solve my question, all i ha to do was test if the folder existed

Comment: Hey Magoo, instead of goto am i able to use other commands???

Comment: Certainly. Whatever command you want (or a series of commands on sequential lines all contained in parentheses.) `goto` is just an example - and probably the most flexible.

Comment: Could you give me an example, for some reason it doesn't want to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some examples - given as "answers" since the formatting is easier to use

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: This one forces errorlevel 0
echo x|find "x" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo errorlevel is 1 or greater) else (echo errorlevel is 0)
:: This one forces errorlevel 1
echo y|find "x" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo errorlevel is 1 or greater) else (echo errorlevel is 0)
:: Now some multi-line responses
:: This one forces errorlevel 0
echo x|find "x" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo errorlevel is 1 or greater
 echo I say again - errorlevel 1 1 or greater
 echo I say a third time - errorlevel 1 1 or greater
) else (
 echo errorlevel is 0
 echo again errorlevel is 0
 echo once again errorlevel is 0
)
:: This one forces errorlevel 1
echo y|find "x" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo Y-errorlevel is 1 or greater
 echo I say again - errorlevel 1 1 or greater for Y
 echo I say a third time - errorlevel 1 1 or greater - Y
) else (
 echo Y-errorlevel is 0
 echo Y-again errorlevel is 0
 echo Y-once again errorlevel is 0
)
::  conditional modification of variable
set /a var=22
echo x|find "x" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (set /a var=%var%+10) else (set /a var=%var%-10)
echo after testing x, var is %var%
set /a var=22
echo y|find "x" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (set /a var=%var%+10) else (set /a var=%var%-10)
echo after testing y, var is %var%
:: You'll need to change these lines to files/directories that exist or don't exist
set "fileexists=c:\pdoxusrs.net"
set "direxists=c:\users"
set "filemissing=c:\missing.net"
set "dirmissing=c:\nothere"
for %%a in ("%fileexists%" "%direxists%" "%filemissing%" "%dirmissing%") do (
 if exist "%%~a" (echo "%%~a" exists) else (echo "%%a" missing)
)
goto :eof
```

Now if `errorlevel` isn't being set to 0/non-zero as you appear to be expecting, then try using `if exist` instead. Probably easier that way, actually. Unfortunately "doesn't work" simply means nothing - we'd need to know exactly what happened, and we'd need you to `edit` your original posting to add-in your current code (or at least, a representative portion.)